# How to setting annotation for each variable with type is Date in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

In my Class, I have many variable with type is Date, and this class using with `@RequestBody`.
I want the value that I receive at variable with type `Date` is format `dd-mm-yyy 00:00:00`,
when I don't using annotation `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "Asia/Tokyo")`
the format I received is `2022-05-02 09:00:00`.

Is there any way I can achieve this without the need of using annotation `@JsonFormat(pattern = yyyy-MM-dd, timezone = "Asia/Tokyo")` at each separate variable ?

Comment: Sounds like `LocalDate` would be more appropriate type for you.

Comment: LocalDate is ok, but I has been using type Date, and too much to change this type.

Comment: Well, switching from an old problematic construct like `java.util.Date` to a newer and more robust like `java.time.LocalDate` shouldn't be too much effort in the long run as you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.